How to use >= and column value in COUNTIFS function
I currently have the following function:
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A;**">=3"**,MySheet!C:C;B3)
To make it dynamic, I want to get the value of 3 in ">=3" to be taken from another cell. In this case the cell F31.
I tried with the following, but can not get it working:
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A;**">="+F31**,MySheet!C:C;B3)
Any help is welcome.
Thanks,
Michael

=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A,">=" & F31,MySheet!C:C, B3) I used commas as seperators, I get the impression there may be a regional thing at play here so if you use ; use those.

Hi Mark, the & made it work, the ; is indeed a regional setting. Thx a lot for the help!!

Happy to help, glad my gut was correct about regional settings and you got your solution. Best of Luck

@Mark, as it says in the tooltip before you type a comment: Avoid answering questions in comments. The question cannot be marked as answered and is useless for the knowlegebase.

@teylyn This is a pretty well documented question/answer on more sites than SO, so following the example of other more active members here I used a comment to quickly resolve it. but this is something that's directly addressed on MSFT site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/count-numbers-greater-than-or-less-than-a-number-453b0ccc-cfaa-4332-ad02-6e148e01aa0a

@MarkS. in that case, flag the question as a duplicate and don't answer it. By answering, you're only encouraging people to ask bad questions instead of teaching them how to search.

To formally answer this question:
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A; ">=" & F31; MySheet!C:C; B3)
It's worth noting the separators are ";" due to regional settings, so other users reading this should consider using "," if it applies to them like so:
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A, ">=" & F31, MySheet!C:C, B3)
